# Set certain XML data to a variable in python

Tags: python, xml

In this code I use a lat and lon I have obtained elsewhere. This is the code snippet

```
import osmapi
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(lat, lon))
dict = location.raw
osmid = dict.get('osm_id', 'default_value_if_null_here')
osmtype = dict.get('osm_type', 'default_value_if_null_here')


if(osmtype == 'node'):
    node_info = requests.get("http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/"+ osmid)
    print node_info.content
```

An example of one instance of the output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.4.0 (1536 thorn-02.openstreetmap.org)" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/">
 <node id="1497969863" visible="true" version="1" changeset="9793574" timestamp="2011-11-11T02:56:41Z" user="ninomax" uid="47976" lat="21.0060360" lon="105.8354524">
  <tag k="amenity" v="marketplace"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Chợ Xanh Kim Liên"/>
 </node>
</osm>
```

I want to be able to put the tags into some variables. This is because I want to check if it is an amenity, and what type of amenity it is so I can input the locations into a database! A quite trivial example of what my ideal outcome is, is as follows.

```
node_tag = node_info.content['tags k']
if node_tag == 'amenity'
    #Add to database
```

I know the above code is wrong but hopefully it will give a general idea of my question. I am new to python so thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to do, but if you're dealing with relatively small XML files, you can use xmltodict ('pip install xmltodict' within your virtualenv) to convert an XML string into a dict object.

To get all the `<tag>` tags with `k="amenity"`, you could do the following:

```
import xmltodict
d = xmltodict.parse(xml_string)
amenity_tags = [tag for tag in d['osm']['node']['tag'] if tag['@k'] == 'amenity']
```

Beware though, that this expects your XML file to only have one `<node>` tag.
If there are multiple ones, d['osm']['node'] will instead be a list and not a dictionary itself.

Hope it helps!